# How to automatically add a single quote at the beginning and end of a user input in python

Tags: python, string

How to automatically add a single quote at the beginning and end of a user input in python so that a user doesn't have to do it manually, what I mean is that when they wanna input:

```
this is a text
```

it automatically becomes:

```
'this is a text'
```

I have some texts that have special characters and they have to be inside single quotes, I'd love to have single quotes automatically added when I input those texts.

Comment: `x = "'" + raw_input("enter whatever:") + "'"`?

Comment: `"'{}'".format(raw_input("Enter some text"))` This is more efficient than reallocating the string 2 times with the `+` operation, though you won't notice that on small inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
userText = raw_input("Enter some text:")
quatedText = "'" + userText + "'"
```